# How to grant EC2 access to SQS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

The docs are very confusing to me. I have read through the SQS access docs. But what really throws me is this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-sqs.html

> You can provide your credential profile like in the preceding example,
>   specify your access keys directly (via key and secret), **or you can
>   choose to omit any credential information if you are using AWS
>   Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles for EC2 instances** or
>   credentials sourced from the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and
>   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables.

1) Regarding what I have bolded, how is that possible? I cannot find steps whereas you are able to grant EC2 instances access to SQS using IAM roles. This is very confusing.

2) Where would the aforementioned environment variables be placed? And where would you get the key and secret from?

Can someone help clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways that applications can discover AWS credentials. Any software using the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) automatically looks in these locations. This includes the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which is a python app that uses the AWS SDK.

Your bold words refer to #3, below:

**1. Environment Variables**

The SDK will look for the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables. This is a *great* way to provide credentials because there is no danger of accidentally including a credentials file in github or other repositories. In Windows, use the System control panel to set the variables. In Mac/Linux, just `EXPORT` the variables from the shell.

The credentials are provided when **IAM users** are created. It would be your responsibility to put those credentials into the environment variables.

**2. Local Credentials File**

The SDK will look in local configuration files, such as:

- `~/.aws/credentials`
- `C:\users\awsuser\.aws\credentials`

These files are great for storing user-specific credentials and can actually store **multiple profiles**, each with their own credentials. This is useful for switching between different environments such as Dev and Test.

The credentials are provided when **IAM users** are created. It would be your responsibility to put those credentials into the configuration file.

**3. IAM Roles on an Amazon EC2 instance**

An IAM role can be associated with an Amazon EC2 instance at launch time. Temporary credentials will then automatically be provided via the instance metadata service via the URL:

```
http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/<role-name>/
```

This will return meta-data that contains AWS credentials, for example:

```
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2015-08-27T05:09:23Z",
  "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
  "AccessKeyId" : "ASIAI5OXLTT3D5NCV5MS",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "sGoHyFaVLIsjm4WszUXJfyS1TVN6bAIWIrcFrRlt",
  "Token" : "AQoDYXdzED4a4AP79/SbIPdV5N8k....lZwERog07b6rgU=",
  "Expiration" : "2015-08-27T11:11:50Z"
}
```

These credentials have inherit the permissions of the IAM role that was assigned when the instance was launched. They automatically rotate every 6 hours (note the `Expiration` in this example, approximately 6 hours after the `LastUpdated` time.

Applications that use the AWS SDK will automatically look at this URL to retrieve security credentials. Of course, they will only be available when running on an Amazon EC2 instance.

**Credentials Provider Chain**

Each particular AWS SDK (eg Java, .Net, PHP) may look for credentials in different locations. For further details, refer to the appropriate documentation, eg:

- [Providing AWS Credentials in the AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/credentials.html)
- [Providing AWS Credentials in the AWS SDK for .Net](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/V3/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-config-creds.html)
- [Providing AWS Credentials in the AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/credentials.html#credential-profiles)

Comment: How do you associate an IAM with an EC2 instance after it is already running? Is that possible?

Comment: Also, the app is asking me to provide the key and the secret. If it changes every 6 hours, how is it possible to provide them to the app?

Comment: You don't provide them. The app automatically looks at that URL and grabs the current credentials. Just assign a role to the EC2 instance at launch time and everything just works! (For example, try using the AWS CLI: `aws s3 ls` will list buckets. See if it works for you!)

Comment: If you have an app that is asking for credentials, then either it's not running on an EC2 instance with a role assigned, or the application has been badly written (by not using the automatic capabilities). If that's the case, you'll have to create an IAM user, assign permissions and then use the credentials associated with that User.